# How to detect orientation change in IEMobile 7 with Javascript?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ie-mobile

is there a way I can detect an orientation change in Internet Explorer Mobile 7? Since no orientationchange event is firred I guess the only way is to look wether the screen width has changed?

Perhaps someone has a better idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean from a web page, not from an application, then no there's no way to detect the orientation change directly, but as you suggest, you could detect the screen width change instead.